# git working directory is out of synch with local code

Tags: git, conflict

After running this, all appears to be fine:

```
git checkout -- . 

git pull upstream master
```

This displays: "nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Then, I add a simple one line comment to a sass file and it compiles.
If I then run `git diff` I see a bunch of apparent conflicts in the complied css.
I would expect that the compiled css would just show the new comment.

I did search the css for conflicts (`<<<<<<< HEAD`) and they correctly don't exist in the file. And, the site runs error free so the code appears to be fine.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Solved - I checked the css file on remote and there are, in fact conflicts (made by another developer). The conflicts weren't on my local because I compiled my sass right after pulling from upstream and that produced a clean CSS locally. So, git was correctly reporting conflicts - that came from the remote.

Comment: Could you add your compiled CSS files to your .gitignore?  This assumes your deploy strategy compiles your SASS for you, then you don't have to worry about version control for these files.

Comment: Excellent suggestion @jmargolisvt but the deploy strategy requires compiled css as well.